# Function Reference/human time diff for future posts

Tags: php, timestamp

Right now I've got future posts displayed on my site, and I was using this code on each post to show when it was published.

```
<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
```

Naturally it shows a post 2 days from now as 2 days ago.  How might I fix it so it says "ago" and maybe "from now"  where applicable?

Comment: Have you tried changing the word `ago` to `from now`? That word isn't a part of the function it's just added on to the end

Comment: Not all my posts are in the future though,  so then older posts would say from now as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out

```
<?php
 if ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'future' ) { 
echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' from 
now';
 } else { 
echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it using `human_time_diff` hook, but it would make it global:

```
function my_time_diff_mins( $since, $diff, $from, $to ) {
   return $since . ($from > $to ? ' from now' : ' ago');
}
add_filter( 'human_time_diff', 'my_time_diff_mins', 10, 4 );
```